# Writing to an XML file in JRuby using Builder

Tags: ruby, xml, jruby, builder

I'm trying to write to an XML file using `Builder` but cannot seem to find `Builder` when I start up my program.  I installed it using `gem install builder` and then used the following in my file, but it does not start up:

```
require 'rubygems'
require_gem 'builder'

def product_xml
    builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new("", 2)
    puts builder.person {
        name("Selene")
        id("1")
        x("2");
        y("3");
    }
end
```

The error that I am getting is:

`LoadError: no such file to load -- rubygems
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at C:\Users\Ron\Dropbox\...\server\.\data\plugins\cmd-dev\dev.r
b:2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install gems inside the JRuby enviroment you must use `jruby -S gem`, not just `gem` (if you are not using RVM).

So you should install Builder with `jruby -S gem install builder`. Once you have installed it, you should just use `require 'builder'`, not `require_gem 'builder'`.